# SQLiteException constraint failed

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a SQLite table which I've created and it works fine when inserting data which is non-zero. However, I need to insert some zero default values and the SQLiteParameter seems to be converting the zero values to null

Can someone explain why I'm getting `@xxxx3=null` instead of `@xxxx3=0` and also how to fix it.

This appears to happen for any numeric field (INTEGER/NUMERIC).

I've put together a simplified example that shows the problem

```
class Program
    {

        private static List<SQLiteParameter> DefaultSystemParameters()
        {
            List<SQLiteParameter> sp = new List<SQLiteParameter>()
            {
                new SQLiteParameter("@xxxx2", 60),
                //new SQLiteParameter("@xxxx3", 1), // Works fine
                new SQLiteParameter("@xxxx3", 0), // Throws 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' NOT NULL constraint failed: tblxxxx.xxxx3    
            };

            return sp;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Add Nuget package - System.Data.SQLite v 1.0.99
            string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath + "db\\";
            string fileName = "test.db";

            string sqlCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblxxxx (" +
                                        "xxxx1 INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                        "xxxx2 INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                                        "xxxx3 INTEGER NOT NULL" +
                                        ")";

            string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tblxxxx (xxxx2, xxxx3) VALUES (@xxxx2, @xxxx3)";

            if (!Directory.Exists(baseDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string connectionString = $"Data Source={baseDir + fileName};Version=3;";
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    //CREATE
                    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCreateTable, connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //INSERT
                        command.CommandText = sqlInsert;
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(DefaultSystemParameters().ToArray());
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx:

> Use caution when you use this overload of the SqlParameter constructor
>   to specify integer parameter values. Because this overload takes a
>   value of type Object, you must convert the integral value to an Object
>   type when the value is zero, as the following C# example demonstrates.

```
Parameter = new SqlParameter("@pname", (object)0);
```